# Manifest file passes Visual Studio test but fails when side loading to Office Web

Tags: office-js

My Excel-js Addin manifest fails when I try to sideload for "Office on the web". The message is "Your Add-In Manifest is not valid". However, within Visual Studio 2017 when I right click on the solution and select "publish" then I click on "Perform a validation check" it passes with the message "Request Correlation ID: 78932cc8-3cff-458b-a211-730bdac4feb8".

1. My add-in sideloads with no issues for the desktop version of Excel. I've tried multiple Windows and Mac machines.
2. I use the button "Package the add-in" from the Publish screen to replace "~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" with the published path.
3. I get the same message from Chrome (Version 75.0.3770.142 64-bit,Edge (44.17763.1.0),and IE (11.0.135).
4. I tried incognito and InPrivate modes for Chrome and Edge respectively.
5. The article [Excel JS Add-In works in Excel but not Excel Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227074/excel-js-add-in-works-in-excel-but-not-excel-online) doesn't seem to apply due to #2 above.
6. I am following the instructions on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing.
7. The addin is hosted using https addresses (not http).
8. I've followed all the manifest guidance I can find. I've even included all the recommended icon sizes from 16 to 128px.
9. I used a GUID generator to create a unique ID.

I would appreciate any help the community can provide.

The manifest can be downloaded at https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvqulgat7h5qzon/CpkManifest.xml?dl=0

Some key elements of the manifest ...

```
<Requirements>
 <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
  <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
 </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
```

```
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
```

**Update - Attempt Using Office Toolbox**

I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest which called for using the office-toolbox to validate the xml. I used the command "npx office-toolbox validate -m CpkManifest.xml" and it came back as "Validation: Passed" with the additional comment

Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:
  - Excel for iPad
  - Excel 2016 for Mac
  - Excel 2016 or later
  - Excel Online

**Update - Attempt Using Schema Validation**

At the same link, it also recommended validating against the schema located at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/tree/master/docs/overview/schemas using the command 
xmllint --noout --schema XSD_FILE XML_FILE

however this returns

Schemas parser error : The XML document 'OfficeAppManifestV1_1.xsd' is not a schema document.
WXS schema OfficeAppManifestV1_1.xsd failed to compile

Note that it is the schema not my xml file that is "not a schema document".

Comment: Did you try the office yeoman generator to build your excel add-in ?

Comment: To test your Office Add-in with Microsoft Edge, two configuration steps are required:

In a Windows Command Prompt, run the following line: `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"`

Enter `“about:flags”` in the Microsoft Edge search bar to bring up the Developer Settings options. Check the `“Allow localhost loopback”` option and restart Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I didn't use the yeoman generator, I used Visual Studio. I did perform the "CheckNetIsolation ..." and "Alllow localhost loopback" in Edge.