# Validated Excel addin manifest works in Excel locally but not in excel online

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, office-js-helpers

I am using Office.js to create an Excel add-in. I am hosting my website on https://localhost:3000 and installed the office dev certs.

When i sideload the manifest.xml locally with `office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop`, the addin works fine.

However, when i want to sideload the add-in by uploading the manifest on excel online, i get the following error:

[image: ExcelOnlineValidationFail]

I validated the manifest using `office-addin-manifest validate .\manifest.xml` and it specifically say that it is targeting Excel online and it is valid.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kMutagene/89e9e36a1462af5bb1a2b454453bc5a8) of the manifest and the validate output.

I already checked [Excel JS Add-In works in Excel but not Excel Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227074/excel-js-add-in-works-in-excel-but-not-excel-online) and it does not seem to applicable in my case, as i am not using visual studio F5 options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Edit: It may be also important to add that the same manifest file sideloaded a few days ago without errors on excel online.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Could you please raise this as an [issue on the office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose)? Please emphasize that it was working a few days ago. Thanks.

Comment: Done, thank you. For anyone that finds this thread here is the [issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1135)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one tip, you can open the Developer Tool by F12, in the Console log, you could see the most error logs.

For this case, the error message is:

```
Invalid manifest from addincommands dev catalog. Exception details: {"name":"AddinManifestError","message":"AddinManifestError: resid: Commands.Url not found"}
```

After adding "Commands.Url" under  , the manifest was side-loaded correctly...

Comment: While i was not able to get the output you got, the error was indeed that there was no commands.url tag. I would imagine however that this is something the validation command should catch no? Anyways it works again so thank you!

Comment: agreed, if Commands.Url tag is necessary for loading on web the validation should catch it and say taht it will load locally but not in web @outlook-add-ins-team-msft